# Domain of $x^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My teacher taught me that:

For $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, the domain of $x^n$ is $\mathbb{R}$

For $n \in \mathbb{Z^-}$ or $n=0$, the domain of $x^n$ is $\mathbb{R\backslash\{0\}}$

***For $n \notin \mathbb{Z}$, the domain of $x^n$ is $(0; \infty)$***

I am unsure if the third line is correct since $-27^{\frac{1}{3}}$ equals $-3$

If it is incorrect, how to say it correctly?

Comment: You mean $(-27)^{1/3}$ instead of $-27^{1/3}=-1\cdot 27^{1/3}$.  In general, the function $x\mapsto x^n$ is defined only for positive arguments if $n$ is arbitrary.  Nevertheless, the equation $x^3 = -27$ has the solution $x=-3$, as you may easily verify.

Comment: Note that every nonzero complex number has  three cube roots.  This includes negative numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that for a specific non-integer $n$, that $x^n$ will be defined over the negative numbers $x$.  $n = \frac{1}{3}$ is a case in point.

However, the intent of your teacher's assertion is that **some** of the non-integer values of $n$ are such that the expression $x^n$ will be undefined for at least some of the negative numbers $x$.

$n = \sqrt{3}$ is a case in point.

What is $~\displaystyle (-1)^{\sqrt{3}}~$?